# jquery contains | target only first ancestor

Tags: jquery, dom, contains, ancestor

I am trying to target and eventually style a string, in this examle BLA, in an HTML page with many tested tables.

For example HTML page:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><table><div><tr><td>BLA</td></tr></div></table></td>
</tr>
```

And the jquery script I use:

```
$("td:contains('BLA')");
```

to do it, but I see that ALL td's are selected.. How can I just get the first td, without all the ancestors?.. 
And if this is possible, how can I add a class to the first  ancestor when going up the DOM tree? (and just this one)

Thank you community

Comment: maybe $("td").html().contains('BLA') ?

Comment: @Eric, that would be true for both `<td>`s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is the last td and not the first since they are returned in DOM hierarchy order.

```
$('td:contains("BLA"):not("td td")').addClass('whatever');
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/92Xj2/

---

***Update** after clarification in comment*

```
$('td:not(:has(td)):contains("BLA")').addClass('whatever');
```

**new demo** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/92Xj2/4/

Comment: Thank you Gaby, Unfortunately in the real-world example, there is no easy way of knowning how many nested <td>'s we'll have.
Plus, I tried modifying this example like that:
http://jsfiddle.net/92Xj2/2/
And it doesn't seem to do what we want.. Isn't there a direct way to target just the first container of "BLA" without going the negation path?

Comment: @George, the `:not(td td)` does not mean two levels deep. It means that the `td` we want is not nested in any depth in another `td`. So it will always be the top-most `td` in the DOM. (*the `td td` is called a **[descendant](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors)** selector*)

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't explain clearly I think, I want to select the lower-most td in the dom not the top-most..

Comment: @George, i see now.. Updated the answer with the opposite selector :)